# How to retrieve a class after wiped out due to unexpected shutdown on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

My PC shut down unexpected after running a project on eclipse (the project saved before that happen.) after reboot and opening eclipse one of the classes content completely wiped out ( it had more that 3000 lines :( ).

how can I retrieve the content?

Eclipse:
Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)
Build id: 20161208-0600

Comment: This is why you should use version control like Git and make commits often.

Comment: Possible recovery methods most likely OS and filesystem specific.  In other words, this is not really an Eclipse question.

Comment: @azurefrog So this is something Eclipse is known for? O_o Glad I ditched it for so many reasons.  Too bad it will be another twenty years before professors stop making their students use it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Eclipse, not about programming.

Comment: @Laf But eclipse questions *do*  "directly involve tools used primarily for programming." and are therefore not off-topic as questions about "general computing hardware or software".

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I wouldn't say it's "known for" it.  I've been using eclipse for well over a decade and never had anything like this happen.

Comment: I have git but I pushed my code 3 days ago and worked over time to meet deadline on today. then that happen. I used the git for retrieve the file but I cannot meet dead line and 3 days hard working gone :((  it is defiantly Eclipse problem, why it clean entire file while it was saved before!!!

Comment: @azurefrog True, I had forgotten this part. fortunately it was closed as a duplicate of a question which seems to answer his question (I hope), so no harm done with my vote. I'll keep that in mind ;)